# The Testing Library's fireEvent.click() not working on my Vanilla JS app

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom, testing-library

Am trying to test if a `<p class="output">` element value is incremented after clicking the  element. The app app works fine when I run it in the browser and click the button because the value increments. However, when I run Jest and use the testing libralie's `fireEvent.click() on the button, my test doesn't not pass because the value is not incremented in the DOM.

Here is my `main.js` file:

```
const incrementBtn = document.querySelector(".increment");
const outputElement = document.querySelector(".output");
let counter = Number(outputElement.textContent);

function increment() {
  outputElement.textContent = counter++;
}

incrementBtn.addEventListener("click", increment);
```

Here is the test in `main.test.js` file:

```
import { fireEvent } from "@testing-library/dom";
...
describe("index.html", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    dom = new JSDOM(html, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
    container = dom.window.document.body;
  });
  // This test passes
  it("renders a heading element", () => {
    expect(container.querySelector("h3")).not.toBeNull();
  });
  // This does not pass
  it("increment a value via JavaScript when the button is clicked", async () => {
    const button = container.querySelector(".increment");
    fireEvent.click(button);  // Firing the event

    expect(container.querySelector(".output")).toHaveTextContent("1"); // This is failing.
  });
});
```

The following is the output from Jest:

```
...
  ● index.html › increment a value via JavaScript when the button is clicked

    expect(element).toHaveTextContent()

    Expected element to have text content:
      1
    Received:
      0

      22 |     fireEvent.click(button);
      23 |
    > 24 |     expect(container.querySelector(".output")).toHaveTextContent("1");
         |                                                ^
      25 |   });
      26 | });
      27 |

      at toHaveTextContent (main.test.js:24:48)
      at tryCatch (main.test.js:2:1)
      at Generator.<anonymous> (main.test.js:2:1)
      at Generator.next (main.test.js:2:1)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (main.test.js:2:1)
      at _next (main.test.js:2:1)
      at main.test.js:2:1
      at Object.<anonymous> (main.test.js:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.199 s
```

Here is my `index.html` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h3>Counter App</h3>
      <p>The Count is:</p>
      <p class="output">0</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="increment">
          <svg class="icon icon-plus"><use xlink:href="#icon-plus"></use></svg>
        </button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <svg>
      <defs>
        <symbol id="icon-plus" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
          <path
            d="M31 12h-11v-11c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1h-6c-0.552 0-1 0.448-1 1v11h-11c-0.552 0-1 0.448-1 1v6c0 0.552 0.448 1 1 1h11v11c0 0.552 0.448 1 1 1h6c0.552 0 1-0.448 1-1v-11h11c0.552 0 1-0.448 1-1v-6c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1z"
          ></path>
        </symbol>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expected the test to pass considering when I click the button manually, it increments. The implementation works fine, but for some reason, using `fireEvent.click()` seems not work.

Comment: Have you considered using [`userEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro) instead? It is asynchronous in nature tho so you will need to use it in an async function and use `await userEvent.click(button)`. Alternatively try wrapping your `expect()` statement inside [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor): does the test pass?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. I will read the doc you linked and try to use it.

Comment: I had a similar problem and the issue was the button selector, since you can click on anything and it wont throw an error, having the wrong selector could be the issue, try adding test-id to the button in question, hope it works

Comment: did you put breakpoint inside of `function increment`? does execution reaches it?